# Creating a bunch of records with FactoryGirl how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm working on a reservation application for hotels.  The problem I am running into is that I'm trying to test my API and the amount of stuff that needs to be created for each test is getting out of hand.  For example, say I want to test my call to get availability/rates for given dates I need to:

- Create a Hotel
- Create a couple roomtypes belonging to the Hotel
- Create rooms for each of the roomtypes
- Create rates for each of the roomtypes
- Create some reservations

Assuming I do 3 roomtypes, 3 rooms each, and 10 days worth of data I have at least 50-60 records being created for each test.  Which seems to be a lot.  Any ideas on how I should handle this?

Comment: Have you looked at seed-fu? (https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu)

Answer (score 0):

Do your objects have to run before EVERY test -- or just prior to all the tests being run? If you need new objects for each test, you'll need to use before :each do ...end.

If you need them created just once per spec page, you can put them in the let x = ... directly after definition of the factory. Like this: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

Also, if you have validation that requires unique names, etc, check out Faker.